# Mule 3.7 transformer with annotations for custom Objects

Tags: mule, transformer-model

I have two custom Classes : Person, Manager. I wrote the following transformer to transform Person to Manager object.
    package com.learning.transformers;

```
import org.mule.api.annotations.ContainsTransformerMethods;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Transformer;

import com.learning.beans.Manager;
import com.learning.beans.Person;

@ContainsTransformerMethods
public class AnnotatedTransformer {

    @Transformer
    public Manager transformToManager(@Payload Person person){
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        manager.setPerson(person);
        manager.setDesignation("Manager");
        return manager;
    }

}
```

My configuraiton file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="anTransformer" name="anT" class="com.learning.transformers.AnnotatedTransformer"/>
    </spring:beans>

    <flow name="mule-learning-transformersFlow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="GlobalHTTPConnector" path="/customTransformation" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.learning.beans.Person" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <!-- <auto-transformer returnClass="com.learning.beans.Manager" /> -->
        <component class="com.learning.components.ManagerLoggingComponent" doc:name="Java" />
    </flow>
</mule>
```

My ManagerLoggingComponent looks like :

```
package com.learning.components;

import com.learning.beans.Manager;
import com.learning.beans.Person;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Payload;

public class ManagerLoggingComponent {
    public void logManager(@Payload Manager manager){
        Person person = manager.getPerson();
        System.out.println("Name: "+person.getName());
        System.out.println("Age: "+person.getAge());
        System.out.println("Designation: "+manager.getDesignation());
    }
}
```

I first send some json input to the flow. That is converted to Person object using json-to-object transformer. Then my component is placed which expects Manager object. I have registered my annotated transformer as spring bean. Hence I expect Person object to be converted to Manager object before passing it to Component. But it is throwing following exception.

> Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to
>   "com.learning.beans.Manager" Type                  :
>   org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException Code                  :
>   MULE_ERROR-109 JavaDoc               :
>   http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
>   Transformer           : JsonToObject{this=d61a0b,
>   name='JsonToManager', ignoreBadInput=false,
>   returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=com.learning.beans.Manager,
>   mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'},
>   sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.io.Reader, mimeType='*/*',
>   encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.net.URL, mimeType='*/*',
>   encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.File, mimeType='*/*',
>   encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String,
>   mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'},
>   SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*',
>   encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*',
>   encoding='null'}]}

Also, while starting the server I found that it is throwing the following error by which I understand that it is un-registering the transformToManager transformer. That might be the reason for not picking up my custom transformer. This is being observed in mule 3.7. 3.5 is working smoothly.

> WARN  2016-03-27 14:01:06,574 [main] org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry: Could not apply shutdown lifecycle to object 'AnnotatedTransformer.transformToManager' after being unregistered.
>    org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: An Expression Evaluator for "payload" is not registered with Mule. Make sure you have the the module for this expression type on your classpath. for example, if you are using an xpath expression you need to have the Mule XML module on your classpath.
>        at org.mule.expression.transformers.AbstractExpressionTransformer.initialise(AbstractExpressionTransformer.java:85) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.expression.ExpressionAnnotationsHelper.getTransformerForMethodWithAnnotations(ExpressionAnnotationsHelper.java:53) ~[mule-module-annotations-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.transformer.AnnotatedTransformerProxy.initialise(AnnotatedTransformerProxy.java:109) ~[mule-module-annotations-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
>        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_72]
>        at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:237) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:71) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.applyPhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:183) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.unregisterObject(AbstractRegistry.java:163) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry$ConfigurableRegistrationDelegate.doRegisterObject(SpringRegistry.java:451) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry$ConfigurableRegistrationDelegate.registerObject(SpringRegistry.java:405) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.registerObject(SpringRegistry.java:253) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.registerObject(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:249) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.registerObject(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:262) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.registerObject(MuleRegistryHelper.java:816) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.registerTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:458) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.transformer.AnnotatedTransformerObjectProcessor.process(AnnotatedTransformerObjectProcessor.java:76) ~[mule-module-annotations-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.spring.processors.TransformerAnnotatedBeanProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(TransformerAnnotatedBeanProcessor.java:30) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.3.jar:3.7.3]
>        ............
>   My request look like

```
{
    "name":"Sai",
    "age" : "100000"
}
```

Any ideas on what is happening here?

**Everything is working as expected in Mule 3.5. Problem is with mule 3.7.**

> Update 1 : Full log of Excetion:

```
    Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to "com.learning.beans.Manager"
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html
Transformer           : JsonToObject{this=13de431, name='JsonToManager', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=com.learning.beans.Manager, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=java.io.Reader, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.net.URL, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.File, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}, SimpleDataType{type=[B, mimeType='*/*',  encoding='null'}]}
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  java.io.Reader:78 (null)
2. Failed to transform from "json" to "com.learning.beans.Manager" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject:133 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
    at org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject.transformMessage(JsonToObject.java:119)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:141)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:69)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:425)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:373)
    at org.mule.expression.MessagePayloadExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(MessagePayloadExpressionEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:318)
    at org.mule.expression.transformers.ExpressionArgument.evaluate(ExpressionArgument.java:116)
    at org.mule.expression.transformers.ExpressionTransformer.transformMessage(ExpressionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:141)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:69)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:366)
    at org.mule.impl.model.resolvers.AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.getPayloadFromMessageWithAnnotations(AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.java:175)
    at org.mule.impl.model.resolvers.AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.getPayloadForMethod(AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.java:161)
    at org.mule.impl.model.resolvers.AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.invoke(AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.java:130)
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:36)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:73)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:120)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:55)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:236)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:154)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.e...
********************************************************************************
```

> Update 2 : I started getting the below exception suddenly. I didn't change any code. It is showing the below exception some times and above exception some other times.

```
    Message               : The object transformed is of type: "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}", but the expected return type is "SimpleDataType{type=com.learning.beans.Manager, mimeType='application/json', encoding='null'}". The current MuleMessage is null! Please report this to mule-esb@mulesoft.com
Type                  : org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerMessagingException.html
Payload               : {NullPayload}
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. The object transformed is of type: "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}", but the expected return type is "SimpleDataType{type=com.learning.beans.Manager, mimeType='application/json', encoding='null'}". The current MuleMessage is null! Please report this to mule-esb@mulesoft.com (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)
  org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer:179 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerMessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: The object transformed is of type: "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}", but the expected return type is "SimpleDataType{type=com.learning.beans.Manager, mimeType='application/json', encoding='null'}". The current MuleMessage is null! Please report this to mule-esb@mulesoft.com
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.checkReturnClass(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:179)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:158)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:69)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:425)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:373)
    at org.mule.expression.MessagePayloadExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(MessagePayloadExpressionEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManager.java:318)
    at org.mule.expression.transformers.ExpressionArgument.evaluate(ExpressionArgument.java:116)
    at org.mule.expression.transformers.ExpressionTransformer.transformMessage(ExpressionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:141)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:69)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:366)
    at org.mule.impl.model.resolvers.AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.getPayloadFromMessageWithAnnotations(AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.java:175)
    at org.mule.impl.model.resolvers.AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.getPayloadForMethod(AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.java:161)
    at org.mule.impl.model.resolvers.AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.invoke(AnnotatedEntryPointResolver.java:130)
    at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:36)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.doInvoke(AbstractJavaComponent.java:73)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:120)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.access$000(AbstractComponent.java:55)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent$1$1.process(AbstractComponent.java:236)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.process(AbstractComponent.java:154)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.m...
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Could you show the full exception for `Failed to transform from "json" to "com.learning.beans.Manager"` ?

Comment: @DavidDossot I have updated the OP.

Comment: Cool, thanks. So basically the issue is due to the fact the `JsonToObject` transformer doesn't recognize the payload type and can't create a stream from it, thus the `null` (see logic here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.7.3/modules/json/src/main/java/org/mule/module/json/transformers/JsonToObject.java#L78-L93 ) Could you put a breakpoint there and check what is the type of the `src` variable?

Comment: Before my custom component (which expects payload of type Manager) is executed as I am using Json-to-object transformer with return class as Person, I am able to see that my payload is of type Person. But I have also registered the transformer as spring bean. I am expecting that before hitting component, mule will automatically convert  Person to Manager using that transformer. But instead of picking up my transformer mule is picking up the json-to-Object transformer and then trying to hit the component which is expecting payload of type Manager. I guess this is the reason for my error.

Comment: @DavidDossot Please take a look at Update 2 in OP. I have observed this issue twice. The error is not consistent. It is showing different errors.

Comment: Thanks for all the extra info. It unfortunately looks like a regression: the fact that the current `MuleMessage` is `null` is an invalid internal state that should never happen. I think this should be reported as a bug to MuleSoft.

Comment: Also I have observed that 
In Mule 3.7, in both
     Transformers and Components, @Lookup annotation is working only on method parameter s. It is not resolving when applied on instance variables.
In Mule 3.6, in 
      Transformers, it is not working on instance variables, but working on method parameters and for 
      Components, it is working on both instance variables and method parameters. I have done these checks to look up MuleContext object.